# Java ASCII output to file

Tags: java, file, ascii

When I try to output an ASCII value to a file, with some characters it returns the wrong value. Example:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

    public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
                                  //Supposed to:
        writeFile("./test.txt"); //write ASCII 147
        readFile("./test.txt"); //read ASCII 147
    }

    public static boolean writeFile(String path){
        try{
            PrintWriter fo = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(path)));
            fo.print((char) 147); //WRITES "?" TO FILE (ASCII 63, NOT 147)
            fo.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean readFile(String path){
        try {
            BufferedReader fi = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            char c[] = fi.readLine().toCharArray();
            System.out.println((int) c[0]); //OBVIOUSLY PRINTS 63 INSTEAD OF 147
            fi.close();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no such thing as "character 147" in ASCII.

You should give a specific encoding which can represent the characters you're interested in - UTF-8 is usually a good choice - and use the same encoding for both reading and writing.

Unfortunately `FileWriter` and `FileReader` don't allow you to specify the encoding, so you'll need `FileOutputStream` and `FileInputStream` wrapped in an `OutputStreamWriter` and `InputStreamReader`:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;

public class Test {

    private static Charset UTF8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        writeFile("./test.txt");
        readFile("./test.txt");
    }

    public static void writeFile(String path) throws IOException {
        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(path), UTF8);
        try {
            writer.write((char) 147);
        } finally {
            writer.close();
        }
    }

    public static void readFile(String path) throws IOException {
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path), UTF8);
        try {
            int c = reader.read();
            System.out.println(c);
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for that answer. I've been looking for a week now, and you solved this for me in thirty seconds. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Some languages conflate the character and octet types (C and C++ being notable examples.) Java `char` types are implicitly UTF-16 and ASCII would have to be represented using the `byte` type. See [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2010/04/i18n-comparing-character-encoding-in-c.html) for a comparison. See [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html) for a Java encoding guide.